# How to add a phone number via Kotlogram to send a direct Telegram message?

Tags: telegram

i currently read all guides about Kotlogram but i don't know how to add a specefic phone number to the contacts to send a message in Java language.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is driven by try-error, and playing with the original [doc](https://kotlogram.readme.io/docs) so there may be a better solution.

this consists of 3 steps

1. add this phone number to your contacts: return with `user-id`
2. use `user-id` from previous step to create `TLInputPeerUser` instance
3. use previously created `TLInputPeerUser` instance to send your message

**surely** you can use this id to send messages to this contact again and again

here's a simple method

```
    private static void sendMessage(TelegramClient client) {

    try {
        Random random = new Random();

        TLVector<TLInputPhoneContact> vector = new TLVector<>();
        TLInputPhoneContact contact = new TLInputPhoneContact(Math.abs(random.nextLong()), "international phone number",
                "firs-name", "last-name");
        vector.add(contact);
        TLImportedContacts importContacts = client.contactsImportContacts(vector, true);

        TLImportedContact importedContact = importContacts.getImported().stream().findFirst().orElse(null);

        TLInputPeerUser inputPeerUser = new TLInputPeerUser();
        inputPeerUser.setUserId(importedContact.getUserId());
        
        //you can save importedContact.getUserId() into db and use it as many as you want

        client.messagesSendMessage(inputPeerUser, "message", Math.abs(new Random().nextLong()));

    } catch (RpcErrorException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you still more clarification please leave a comment (:

Answer (score 0):

First, bots can't send messages to users without `/START`.

You can't add contacts via phone number with bots, but there has a geek way, you can use `sendContact` to obtain .result.contact.**user_id**, then you can send as normal.

See following example:

[image: Awesome Telegram Bot]

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. but as i mentioned above im using Kotlogram Api so this is not what i was talking about.